# Extjs 4 get form Id

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 4.2, The below is the code. I have defined the form Id, but button event can't get the value. the weird thing is, when I submit the form, it will go to server side and I can get the field value.

How to the ID value ?

```
Ext.define('App.view.QuestionForm',{
    extend      : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.QuestionForm',
    requires    : ['Ext.data.Store'],

    bodyPadding  : 5,  
    defaults  : {xtype  : 'textfield' },

    id: 'question_form',

    initComponent   : function(){
        var me = this;
        //me.id = 'question_form';

        me.items = me.buildItems();
        me.dockedItems = me.buildToolbars();
        me.callParent();
    },


    buildItems : function(){
        return [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'ID',  
            name: 'id',
            xtype: 'textfield', 
            anchor: '100%'
        },        
        ];
    },
    buildToolbars : function(){
        return [{
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            items : [

            {
                xtype: 'button', 
                text:'Save', 
                handler: function(){
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                     console.log("form :"+form.id); //undefined 

                    form.submit({url: 'rs/question/save'});                
                }
            },       


            ]
        }];
    }

});
```

thanks

Comment: What did you use instead of the above code? I am getting the same error `undefined` for `this.up('form').getForm();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define id of the `Ext.form.Panel` component. 
So in handler just use:

```
var form = this.up('form');
```

for getting instance of the  `Ext.form.Panel` component.

When you call method `getForm()` of the `Ext.form.Panel` component it returns underlying `Ext.form.Basic` component which does not have defined ID.